# Strict/strong functors are co/reflective inside lax functors, the coendy way

Tags: ct.category-theory

Bozapalides' [remarks on lax presheaves](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256047482) show that the category $[{\cal A}^\text{op}, {\bf Cat}]$ is reflective and coreflective inside the category of lax functors, lax natural transformations and modifications ${\cal A}^\text{op}\to {\bf Cat}$.

But what is $[{\cal A}^\text{op}, {\bf Cat}]$ again? Judging from the action on morphisms of the 2-functor ${\cal A}(-,=)$ I would guess they are strict functors, but this is never specified.

And again: is there a way to deduce from the definition that (as it must be) the unit of the adjunction $\check{(-)}\dashv i$ ($i$ the inclusion $[{\cal A}^\text{op}, {\bf Cat}] \hookrightarrow Fun({\cal A}^\text{op}, {\bf Cat})$) is an isomorphism on strict/strong components?